# I try to trigger JobConfigurationLoad and it says 404 job not found. My Dataset Location, Processing Location and storage location are all same

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to trigger JobConfigurationLoad and it says 404 job not found. My Dataset Location, Processing Location and storage location are all same.

Comment: This is related to BigQuery Load API

Comment: Please change the title of the post to "BigQuery Load API returns 404". In your question, please say how you are invoking the API. Are you using a client library? Are you using curl? If so, please post the code.  When you say "dataset location ... location" are all same -- same as what?